# Error deploying application on server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to get my asp.net application working on the server(windows 2008 R2). I have created the virtual drectory/application in IIS7.5. When I try to browse the app. from IIS, it defaults to another web site (intranet site of the company). When I looked at the log files this is what found.

`2013-04-27 11:17:00 ::1 DEBUG /TOrders/default.aspx - 80 - ::1 - 401 0 0 2
2013-04-27 11:17:02 ::1 GET /TOrders/default.aspx - 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0) 302 0 0 11
2013-04-27 11:17:12 ::1 DEBUG /TOrders/default.aspx - 80 - ::1 - 200 0 0 1`

Also not sure why the log shows 'Mozilla' when i am using IE

Some things that I tried include
I added  in web.config
In  IIS, I enabed Anonymous Authentication and changed the Application pool identity to "Specific user"
I also installe vs2010 on the server to debug and put a debug point in glabal.ascx and default.aspx - Doesn't seem to reach here at all.

Note: This app works perfecly on my local machine (with iis 7.5)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I had to install Windows Authentication on the server and set it to 'Enabled' in IIS(under Authentication) and set Anyonymous to 'Disabled'